# PostgreSQL How to combine regex_split_to_array and foreach loop

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, foreach, postgresql-9.1

I have a column with multiple comma-separated values (up to 50, country names). Those values must be replaced with a particular code (country code, ISO3) from another table.

Internet search has lead me to split the values to an array ([regex_split_to_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)) and to use a loop through the array ([FOREACH LOOP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html))

I get the general concept but I am struggling at least with syntax (pqsl beginner).

**Approach:**

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
m   varchar[];
arr varchar[]; -- declare array
BEGIN
-- split the comma-separeted values to array and insert into the array
SELECT (regexp_split_to_array(country, E','))
  into arr
FROM tablename
WHERE xy;
FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
LOOP
-- update/replace the value with a function
RAISE NOTICE 'another function(%)', m;
END LOOP;

END
$do$
```

I assume that filling the array doesn't work that way..

PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: And why are you using an un-supported and outdated Postgres version?

Comment: I am not the server-admin, I know about that and already reported it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this. You can do this with a single statement:

Assuming the following setup:

```
create table  tablename
(
  id integer primary key,
  country_list text
);

create table lookup
(
  iso_code varchar(3),
  country text
);

insert into tablename
values
(1, 'Germany, Austria, Italy'),
(2, 'Austria, France'),
(3, 'France, Switzerland');

insert into lookup
values
('de', 'Germany'),
('at', 'Austria'),
('it', 'Italy'),
('fr', 'France'),
('ch', 'Switzerland');
```

You can unnest the countries using:

```
select s.id, trim(unnest(string_to_array(s.country_list, ','))) as country
from tablename s;
```

Given the sample data above that returns the following:

```
id | country    
---+------------
 1 | Germany    
 1 | Austria    
 1 | Italy      
 2 | Austria    
 2 | France     
 3 | France     
 3 | Switzerland
```

This can be joined to your lookup table:

```
with normalized as (
   select s.id, trim(unnest(string_to_array(s.country_list, ','))) as country
   from tablename s
)
select n.id, n.country, l.iso_code
from normalized n
  join lookup l on l.country = n.country;
```

This returns the following:

```
id | country     | iso_code
---+-------------+---------
 1 | Austria     | at      
 1 | Germany     | de      
 1 | Italy       | it      
 2 | Austria     | at      
 2 | France      | fr      
 3 | France      | fr      
 3 | Switzerland | ch
```

You can aggregate the list of ISO codes back into your de-normalized structure:

```
with normalized as (
   select s.id, trim(unnest(string_to_array(s.country_list, ','))) as country
   from tablename s
)
select n.id, string_agg(l.iso_code,',') as iso_list
from normalized n
  join lookup l on l.country = n.country
group by n.id;
```

And that can be used to replace the values in the target table:

```
with normalized as (
   select s.id, trim(unnest(string_to_array(s.country_list, ','))) as country
   from tablename s
), translated as (
  select n.id, string_agg(l.iso_code,',') as iso_list
  from normalized n
    join lookup l on l.country = n.country
  group by n.id
)
update tablename st
  set country_list = t.iso_list
from translated t
where t.id = st.id;
```

After that the contents of `tablename` is:

```
id | country_list
---+-------------
 1 | it,at,de    
 2 | fr,at       
 3 | fr,ch
```

---

A **much** better solution would be to properly normalize your model and create a many-to-many mapping table between `tablename` and the `lookup_table`